# Ropstens test net. How do I solve this?

Tags: ropsten, test

The picture below shows the wallet status of the Ropstens test server.
How long do I have to wait to resolve it?
How do I solve this?
Where should I ask for help?
My wallet is not working.

[image: The picture below shows the wallet status of the Ropstens test server. How long do I have to wait to resolve it? How do I solve this? Where should I ask for help? My wallet is not working.]

Comment: Sorry, no idea what it says since it's not in English. Please post the information in English, since that is the common language here.